# Adding document language and title for accessibility in LaTex

Tags: accessibility

I wonder if anyone knows how to add a note on language (English) and a document title (e.g., A report for xxx) in LaTex for accessibility requirements.

I make .pdf documents in LaTex first, then I add tags using Adobe's Autotag Document function. Lastly, I run a Full Check to find out if there are any tagging issues. The  check on Primary Language and Title failed.

Is there any way these can be added in LaTex before .pdf documents are created?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not saying much about your document. But you can add a title and a language e.g. with hyperref:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[pdftitle=Titel,pdflang=en-US]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
abc

\end{document}
```